# Python cause of KeyError

Tags: python, json, keyerror

What I should to do, to avoid `Keyerror` in my code, I'm a noob :)
I load json and print all the values ​​from the array by tag `status_name`, but the algorithm fails on an `Keyerror`, how can I handle it and then save the resulting list to a file?

```
import json
with open(r'.json', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

for data in data:
    print(data['status_name'])
```

I get data from all tags `status_name` on request, but when the request reaches a tag where is no tag `status_name`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 6, in <module>
KeyError: 'status_name'

Print Output:
v
v
v
m
u
u
m
v
v
v
v
```

I want to print none or skip such blocks

Comment: Did you check that the file contains what you think it should  contain? What do you think `KeyError` means? What should happen if there is no `'status_name'` entry in a given `data`? When you say "save the resulting list to a file", what list are you talking about?

Comment: This is problematic: `for data in data`. You are overwriting `data`.

Comment: @jarmod `for data in data:` is certainly poor, but it alone is not the cause of the problem because I don't believe the original value of `data` is needed any longer: `data = [0,1, 2, 3]; for data in data: print(data)` runs and produces the correct output.

Comment: @Booboo agree and that's largely why it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel updated the topic, I get data from all tags `status_name` on request, but when the request reaches block where is no tag `status_name`, I get: KeyError: `status_name`

Comment: Okay, so when the request reaches a tag where there is no tag status_name, *what do you want to happen instead*?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel I want to print none or skip such blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of handling the error:

**Method 1**

```
import json

with open(r'.json', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

new_data = []
for d in data: # use different variable name
    # is d a dictionary and does it have 'status_name' as a key?
    if isinstance(d, dict) and 'status_name' in d:
        new_data.append(d)

"""    
# the above loop can be reduced to the more "Pythonic" list comprehension:
new_data = [d for d in data if isinstance(d, dict) and 'status_name' in d]
"""
with open('new_json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    json.dump(new_data, fp)
```

**Method 2**

```
import json

with open('.json', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

new_data = []
for d in data: # use different variable name
    # assume d is a dictionary with key 'status_name'
    try:
        value = d['status_name']
    except Exception:
        pass # don't append d
    else:
        new_data.append(d) # no exception so append d

with open('new_json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    json.dump(new_data, fp)
```

Comment: @ Booboo Thanks! I corrected it a little, it works!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your data has no key named 'status_name'. Try printing only the data first, and see what is the actual key for what you're looking for.

As for saving it in a file, you can open a file with the 'w' mode, and write the data at the end of the loop. Like this:

file = open(data.txt, 'w')

for d in data:

print(d['status_name'])

file.write(d)

I changed 'data' for 'd' cause it was a bit confusing.

And don't forget to close the file after the loop.

Comment: I'd suggest using a context manager to save the file, just like OP did to read it.

Comment: You need to fix your indentation (and close your output file).

Comment: If 'status_name' is not a valid key, your code will also throw an exception. But this is probably not the real cause of the OP's exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
import xlwt
import json
with open(r'name.json', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)
channels = set() # unique data
for item in data['items']: 
    if 'status_name' in item: #checking if there is a tag, bypass Keyerror
        channels.add(item['status_name'])
        print(item['status_name'])
print(channels) # print unique data

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet("Sheet Name")
# Writing on specified sheet
sheet.write(0, 0, 'Channels')
row = 1
for channel in sorted(channels):
    sheet.write(row, 0, channel)
    row += 1
workbook.save("name.xls")
```